# Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException WebAuthenticatorActivity

Tags: android, xamarin, oauth

I have a Xamarin.Android project where I want to use Xamarin.Auth package to let user authenticate through Google sign-in page.

Here is my code at MainActivity.cs

```
OAuth2Authenticator auth = new OAuth2Authenticator
        (
            clientId: "client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            scope: "",
            authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth"),
            redirectUrl: new Uri("http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"),
            // switch for new Native UI API
            //      true = Android Custom Tabs and/or iOS Safari View Controller
            //      false = Embedded Browsers used (Android WebView, iOS UIWebView)
            //  default = false  (not using NEW native UI)
            isUsingNativeUI: false
        );

        auth.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
        {
            // UI presented, so it's up to us to dimiss it on Android
            // dismiss Activity with WebView or CustomTabs
            this.Finish();

            if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // Use eventArgs.Account to do wonderful things
            }
            else
            {
                // The user cancelled
            }
        };

        var ui_object = auth.GetUI(this);
        StartActivity(ui_object);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
```

I allways ends up with folowing exception when calling auth.GetUI(this) method:

```
JNIEnv.FindClass(Type) caught unexpected exception: Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: md53c585be971e02235139fd1aef11fc0c1.WebAuthenticatorActivity ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md53c585be971e02235139fd1aef11fc0c1.WebAuthenticatorActivity"
```

Can anyone see why it would do this? I've tried to google it but looks like I'm only one who gets this type of error.

I have VS 2017 15.5.2 and using Android 8.0 API 26

Comment: Got a `classes.dex` handy? Should be located in `obj/{configuration}/android/bin`

Comment: Try clearing out your `bin/obj` folders and rebuild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I remove/add my nuget packages to Xamarin.Auth and PCLCrypto and everything is working now. Google sign-in page is displayed when app starts.